# Looking for archive supporting Java and strong encryption

Tags: java, encryption, archive, encryption-symmetric

I am looking for a "standard" archiver format (ZIP, 7ZIP, etc.) that is supported by a pure Java library and has strong (AES-128) encryption.

I need a format that people can decrypt using off-the-shelf software for Windows and OsX.

My understanding is that ZIP encryption prior to version PKZIP 9.0 (Zip 2.0) was very weak, and that PKWARE has never published the AES-256 file version.

The format need only support secret-key encryption (public-key is not required or desired).

I can't use BouncyCastle Open-PGP because their JAR files must be signed with their key and we need to also sign with our code-signing key for Java Web Start. Some of our customers are running old builds of Java 6 (< 14) and can't upgrade. Builds of Java 6 prior to 14 did not support signing with multiple keys.

Comment: @Martijn Courteaux: As much as I like Linux, **none** of my customers use it.

Comment: That's indeed a sad fact of life :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the [Zip4j](http://www.lingala.net/zip4j/) library:

> **Key features:**
>
> - Create, Add, Extract, Update, Remove files from a Zip file
> - Read/Write password protected Zip files
> - Supports AES 128/256 Encryption
> - Supports Standard Zip Encryption
> - Supports Zip64 format
> - Supports Store (No Compression) and Deflate compression method
> - Create or extract files from Split Zip files (Ex: z01, z02,...zip)
> - Supports Unicode file names
> - Progress Monitor
>
> **License:**
>
> - Zip4j is released under Apache License, Version 2.0.

Comment: Importantly for @Ralph, the AES encryption is apparently compatible and interoperable with the WinZip AES format. It thus should be decryptable using later versions of Winzip and 7zip.

Comment: @Marcelo: That sounds like **exactly** what I need. I'll check it out. Thanks.

Comment: @Marcelo: I tried Zip4J, but it does not seem to produce correct CRCs for AES encrypted ZIPs, at least not CRCs which either WinZip, 7Zip, or Archiver (OsX) find correct. I read through both the examples and source code. It seems to set the CRC to 0 for all AES-encrypted files. Thanks, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I don't know enough about your project, but why don't you create your **zip** using the default Java API. And then encrypt the zip using AES-128. Or if you want, you can first encrypt the content and then zip it.

Comment: Since an encrypted file will appear to be random it will normally compress very little. Probably better to zip first then encrypt.  Your idea of using the two specialist libraries for their specialist functions is a good one +1

Comment: @rossum How can this fulfill this OP's requirement: "I need a format that people can decrypt using off-the-shelf software for Windows and OsX."?

Comment: @Marcelo: AES was specified by the OP.  Zip is available off the shelf.  Any use of AES is going to require use of the correct key, padding and IV so it is going to be more complex then just clicking on a file.

Comment: @rossum: I used AES as an example. I don't care what algorithm it uses as long as it is strong. I believe that the original ZIP format used a 40-bit key, breakable in a few hours on 2011 commodity hardware.